# Does anyone know a brocade emulator?

Tags: networking

I'm studying to get BCNE, but is so difficult to study without equipment. Is there a good brocade emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is beta emulator for brocade switch, but it has several bugs, link: 
http://code.google.com/p/brocade-sim/downloads/list

GL